# java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) but port is only used once

Tags: java, sockets, debugging, server

after searching online, BindException occurs when a port is already in use. But i've only used this port number once. Here is my code.

```
public class ServerUI extends Application {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public ServerUI() throws IOException {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ServerUI server = new ServerUI();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();

        Controller controller = (Controller)loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

According the stack trace, the error occurs on line5 when I try to create an instance of ServerUI on line10. Not sure how to debug this. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

To free a port on a **Windows** computer, run command prompt as *administrator* and execute the following commands:

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:1111 // finds the process using the port
taskkill /F /PID 10880 // change 10880 with your PID number which you can see from the previous command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your framework version and development environment, this usually means there is an old version of this app running. Check that all other instances of the app have been stopped/killed.